# Access View added graphically to iOS app in code

Tags: ios

Rather new to Xcode and iOS dev, however - there's something which might be kinda basic I can't seem to find an example of anywhere.

I want to access a View I added to my story board using code so I can modify it (specifically, it's a FBLoginView I want to realloc with permissions set to it, but it does not really matter).

How can I do this?

Comment: What you need is called an outlet, search for `IBOutlet` and I guarantee you'll find what you need.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what exactly you need, but try looking at `UIStoryboard` class.

You instantiate by calling `[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:(NSString *)name bundle:(NSBundle *)storyboardBundleOrNil]` and then create view controller it contains by calling `[myStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier]`.

If you need to access Storyboard that is already loaded, you can do it via `storyboard` property on any `UIViewController` instantiated from a storyboard.